# Will sqlite always inserts new records at end of the table?

Tags: database, sqlite, insert

When we insert a record to a sqlite table is it always inserted at the end of the table or if records were previously deleted is there a possibility the records will first fill in the empty space before adding to the end?

Answer (score 3):

SQLite, like many databases, doesn't really have a concept of position of a record (as far as the typical user is concerned), other than that tables will automatically be given a **rowid** which will be a unique identifier that generally increases by 1 (not that this is guaranteed). Freed **rowid** numbers could be re-used (not if AUTOINCREMENT is used) but not until rowid 9223372036854775807 had been used. This **rowid** is generally the most efficient means of accessing a row (record).  The following explains a lot about the **rowid** column [SQLite Autoincrement](https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html).

- When defining a table the WITHOUT ROWID can be used (for more recent versions of SQlite), in which case there will be no **rowid** column.
- Frequently an alias of the **rowid** column is used. An alias is defined by coding ?? INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (with the optional AUTOINCREMENT keyword).

  - **Note** VACUUM may change **rowid**'s if no alias has been assigned.

If you want rows in a particular order then you use the **ORDER BY** keyword when querying the table(s). In which case the result set is ordered.

However, again, like many databases, it does try to efficiently manage storage, although use may be made of the VACUUM command [SQL As Understood By SQLite VACUUM](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html) or by turning on auto vacuum mode via a pragma.